# Silverstripe keeps adding style="font-size: 10px;"

Tags: html, tinymce, font-size, silverstripe

I built a silverstripe website and one of my users is having an odd problem.
Any time she tries to make a bulleted list it set style="font-size: 10px;".

Sometimes it's in the < li >, sometimes it's a < span style="font-size: 10px;">...< /span>, and sometimes it's both.  I've watched her create a list and she's not doing anything out of the ordinary. She's using Safari on a Mac.  I've tried recreating the error on Safari/Mac but I can't recreate the error.  It seems like it might be specific to her computer or her account but I can't find anything.  Does anyone know what might be wrong?

The HtmlEditorConfig looks like this,

```
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')
    ->setOption('extended_valid_elements', 
        "img[class|src|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name|usemap|data*],
        iframe[src|name|width|height|align|frameborder|marginwidth|marginheight|scrolling|mozallowfullscreen|webkitallowfullscreen|allowfullscreen|frameborder],
        object[width|height|data|type],param[name|value],
        map[class|name|id],area[shape|coords|href|target|alt],
        figure,
        figcaption,
        tabindex,
        form[method|action|id],
        input[type|id|value|name]"
    );
```

Comment: Could be a TinyMCE configuration problem. See https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-tinytidy for a kitchensink example how to configure the `HTMLEditorField`. Can you check your config for it?

Comment: Also: what version of SilverStripe are you using? Can you share some demo code?

Comment: I haven't installed the TinyMCE addon, should I?
I'm using 3.5.3

Comment: It's not really a module but a good howto for configuring tinymce through SilverStripe.

Comment: This also happens when you copy text from e.g. Word; it also copies some styling from there. You need to press "Paste from Word" to copy text with basic styling or "Paste as plain text" first to just copy the text. I tend to use the latter and re-style in the browser.

Comment: @wmk I've checked and she's not pasting from anything.